# Execution failed for task ' app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. PROCESS COMMAND CMD FINISHED WITH NON-ZERO EXIT VALUE 1

Tags: android, flutter

Here is an image you can see  detailed erro in this image explain if you faced this problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7UPV.png)

I several times run and builded the program but couldn't solve the issue.
I am running a flutter project but not running the app on android phone or virtual device.